# Angular 9 "No value provided for @angular/core symbol 'ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef'." (IVY)

Tags: angular, angular9

I updated my Angular app to version 9 today and it works fine without IVY compiler.

As soon as I enable Ivy I get the following error (on application startup) and have no clue how to proceed.

It appears to be something to do with change detector refs and pipes, but while I am using  custom pipes none use a change detector.

> runtime.js:26 ERROR Error: No value provided for @angular/core symbol
>   'ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef'.
>       at R3JitReflector.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.R3JitReflector.resolveExternalReference
>   (vendor.js:36836)
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitEmitterVisitor.visitExternalExpr
>   (vendor.js:36772)
>       at ExternalExpr.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.ExternalExpr.visitExpression
>   (vendor.js:31428)
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.AbstractEmitterVisitor.visitInvokeFunctionExpr
>   (vendor.js:36217)
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.AbstractJsEmitterVisitor.visitInvokeFunctionExpr
>   (vendor.js:36572)
>       at InvokeFunctionExpr.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.InvokeFunctionExpr.visitExpression
>   (vendor.js:31285)
>       at vendor.js:36401
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.AbstractEmitterVisitor.visitAllObjects
>   (vendor.js:36420)
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.AbstractEmitterVisitor.visitAllExpressions
>   (vendor.js:36401)
>       at JitEmitterVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.AbstractEmitterVisitor.visitInstantiateExpr
>   (vendor.js:36257)

---

As requested:

```
{
  "name": "mycompanyname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@datorama/akita": "^4.17.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ng-router-store": "^4.0.0",
    "@datorama/akita-ngdevtools": "^3.0.2",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/applepayjs": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/braintree-web": "^3.47.0",
    "@types/fb": "0.0.23",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.51",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.40",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.51",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/mailcheck": "^1.1.31",
    "@types/smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/universal-analytics": "^0.4.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/vkbeautify": "^0.99.2",
    "@types/youtube": "0.0.38",
    "braintree-web": "^3.56.0",
    "core-js": "^3.5.0",
    "dependency-tree": "^7.2.0",
    "fast-safe-stringify": "^2.0.7",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.17.1",
    "immer": "^5.0.1",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "json2typescript": "^1.2.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-web": "^5.5.10",
    "mailcheck": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-in-viewport": "^6.0.3",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-markdown": "^8.2.1",
    "ngx-md": "^8.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "normalizr": "^3.4.1",
    "pretty-data": "^0.40.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-etc": "^9.6.2",
    "safe-json-stringify": "^1.2.0",
    "slugify": "^1.3.6",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "vkbeautify": "^0.99.3",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "akita-schematics": "^2.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.4",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

---

I'm stepping through in the browser now to see what I can find.

The missing symbol is sometimes present in `R3JitReflector.context` (where it is looking for it) and sometimes not there:

Error:
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: If it's possible can you please reproduce it in a small github repository?

Comment: @yurzui I have no idea if I can or not! Was hoping somebody knew based on the error what was the issue.  I would have made this a github issue but didn't have time to do it justice (it was 1:30am) I can maybe try soon but I could see it easily taking 5 hours just to figure out what I need to put in to make it break :-/

Comment: Got it. Can you please add your `package.json`? We need to understand what you're using and which versions

Comment: @yurzui thanks - I've added it to the question. Haven't had a chance to look at this today but try to delve into it a little more now. If you have any suggestions on what to check I can take a look - also going to comment out things and see if I can coax it to load.

Comment: Can you open `../@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js` file in browser console and search for `'ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef': ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: From what I see you're running Ivy in Jit mode but aot should be enabled by default in angular.json `"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,` But the error can be still there. It might be some incompatibility with deps

Comment: I do see `'ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef': ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef` present. I think I'll try completely wiping out my node_modules because in the past that's often fixed certain obscure errors like this. Also one thing that's confused me a lot is whether I have the correct settings for esm / fesm. I see `Compiling @angular/router : module as esm5` when I compiled the first time - is that the correct expected target?

Comment: Yep, thats correct behaviour. Angular 9 runs ngcc compiler in order to be compatible with Ivy. Removing node_modules and reinstalling is a good idea.

Comment: If the error will be still presented I would advise you to debug it directly in the browser

Comment: I tried to reproduce it with a Pipe that injects ChangeDetectorRef and all code worked well in those lines where your error callstack points

Comment: I'm doing some process of elimination tracing now - I had to stop myself last night - was too excited :-) I'm adding a couple screenshots now - sometimes the `ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef` is present in `R3JitReflector.context` and sometimes not.

Comment: It means that there is a case when `context` was incorrectly passed to the `R3JitReflector` Can you go through callstack and identify the Pipe?

Comment: Please look at the example https://monosnap.com/file/j9TZ6pZT6MP58WMie2ubVMATL4FdLX

Comment: If I wipe out my app.component.html and just put `{{ animal | async }}` where `animal = of('cat');` then it does work. checking now ...

Comment: Walking up the stack trace from the actual error gets me to a template with just a simple async pipe `<rr-checkout-steps-bar *ngIf="config.wizard.stepsBar$ | async" [header]="checkoutStepsHeader$ | async"></rr-checkout-steps-bar>`

Comment: yurzui - I'm adding an answer with debugging steps - still updating it now

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; If you are getting this error message make sure:

- your `ts.config.json` and `angular.json` file are up to date. I recommend installing a new project with the CLI and then comparing side by side
- if you have `ts.config.json` or `ts.config.app.json` in two places (`app` and `src`) make sure you are doing it deliberately :-)

---

#### This is an answer in progress - not yet a full answer

So the underlying problem is `R3JitReflector` sometimes gets instantiated *without* a `ɵɵinjectPipeChangeDetectorRef` provided on the `context` object and when it gets to `resolveExternalReference` it expects to find it but can't.

So step 1 was to find a stack trace for the creation of the `R3JitReflector` that subsequently failed.

Since it's difficult to change the source (I am using `ng serve`) I added a sneaky breakpoint with a side effect to the constructor that would create a stack trace I could later inspect).

[image]

So now when it is about to throw an error I can inspect `this.stack` to get the original stacktrace. Here it is:

```
Error
    at eval (eval at R3JitReflector (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:36828:9), <anonymous>:1:15)
    at new R3JitReflector (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:36828:9)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompilerFacadeImpl.jitExpression (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:49155:79)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompilerFacadeImpl.compileFactory (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:49134:21)
    at Function.get (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:70418:45)
    at eval (ng:///UnobserveHelperService/ɵprov.js:4:110)
    at JitEvaluator.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitEvaluator.executeFunction (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:36744:78)
    at JitEvaluator.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitEvaluator.evaluateCode (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:36732:21)
    at JitEvaluator.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitEvaluator.evaluateStatements (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:36701:21)
    at CompilerFacadeImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompilerFacadeImpl.jitExpression (https://dev.example.com:44300/vendor.js:49155:37)"
```

I now finally see my own code `UnobserveHelperService` which has the following constructor:

[image]

So now I'm onto something - I have a `ChangeDetectorRef` here...

Fortunately `ChangeDetectorRef` is the kind of thing you can comment out and your code will basically still work... and that turns out to be the case.

### My app now loads and seems to be working fine!!!

OK so back to what is `UnobserveService`. It takes a tree of observables and 'unwraps' them to a POJO for convenience.

But that's not really relevant - what's important is how it's instantiated.

First of all let's make sure the `private` is irrelevant and make it `public cdr` instead just in case... OK still fails - as expected.

Lets's see if we ever even get as far as the constructor.

```
@Injectable()
export class UnobserveHelperService implements OnDestroy
{
    constructor(public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
    {
        throw new Error('constructor for UnobserveService threw error');
    }
```

Interestingly we don't, but not really surprising I suppose - it's breaking long before we get here.

So anyway `UnobserveHelperService` is a service provided by a component - one of my failing URLS this is `CheckoutComponent`.

`providers: [ UnobserveHelperService ]`

Interestingly the `CheckoutComponent` does not **itself** take `cdr` as a dependency. So let's see if that makes a difference by adding `cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` to the component.

That didn't seem to make a difference (also tried putting cdr before and after my UnobserveHelperService).

OK so now let's just make a simple project to see if we can duplicate this...

Created a new empty angular 9 project and the following does **not** fail:

```
@Injectable()
export class UnobserveHelperService
{
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
    {
       console.log(this.cdr);
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss'],
  providers: [ UnobserveHelperService ]
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private helper: UnobserveHelperService) {
    console.log(this.helper);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
}
```

If I put this exact service definition back into my main app then it fails again.

One thing I noticed when compiling my new project is I get :

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015

but my project gives me

Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/common : module as esm5
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : module as esm5

Could this be related?

Last update: I've commented out virtually my entire application and still seeing the issue. Cannot duplicate it in a sample project. My dog needs his walk now! will try again tomorrow.

#### to be continued...

Comment: looks like the issue may have been my `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` were at the wrong level (inside `src` instead of a level above `src`). I'm now seeing a lot of compiler errors I didn't see before (typescript version related) - so will need to fix those first and hopefully get it running.

Comment: I have my tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json a level above src, and still have the same issue as you. Strangely, a colleague using the exact same source does not have the issue on his machine

Comment: @dave I managed to work around this at the time and I’m actually not convinced the taco dog was the only problem (taco dog = tsconfig). I jumped on v9 faster than I planned so had enough other things to fix. Are you and your colleague both definitely running AOT, IVY and save angular? I think AOT false breaks this.

Comment: D'Oh! Apparently AOT is off by default when using ng serve. Using the --aot switch solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AOT disabled can cause this problem. Make sure it’s enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My case was an angular version mismatch. I used my components lib (ng v.9) in my main app (ng v10) and had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a stupid amount of time trying to fix this. In the end, all I needed to do was the following.

Open **tsconfig.app.json**, and add this block to the bottom:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Comment: Take a break for now (!) - but just be aware that ivy will be going away in the not too distant future and you'll lose out on a lot of optimizations with it off.  You have AOT on? Has this project been around for a long time and if so compare the config files side by side with a new clean angular project.